# How to select distinct column values from mysql database in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I need to retrieve distinct value from query set and display it on a div.

Here is my model.py:

```
class Persons(models.Model):      
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    salary = models.IntegerField
    doj = models.DateField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = "test"
```

Here is my view.py:

```
def calender(request):
    distinctyears = Persons.objects.all().values('doj').distinct()
year = {
    "Items": distinctyears
}
return render(request, "home.html", year)
```

Here is my html :

```
<div>
   {% for item in Items %}
         <div class="numbers">{{ item.doj }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My code is not working. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: In Render context you are passing years not `Persons`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.distinct([*fields])` at the end of your query.

Here's the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

As stated all fields in a record are checked. Mostly likely in your case you are getting records with different field values (more likely a case if you are queries multiple tables ManyToMany or ForeignKey relations).